# How to toggle "Tap to Click" on macOS sierra

Tags: macos, mac, touchpad, macos-sierra

So I wanted to toggle this setting from the terminal. I grep'd through `defaults read | grep -i click` and spotted that toggling this through "System Preferences" changed keys:

- `com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking`
- `com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad Clicking`

I tried to change them but haven't actually updated this "Tap to click" setting (even if I see mentioned values change after I do it manually through System preferences). Am I missing some other keys I should update using `defaults write` command?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool true
defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
```

**edit**:

Don't try. [Read this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259820/macos-sierra-breaks-a-lot-of-terminal-defaults-write-commands-tap-to-click-fo).